# Is there a way to print a message after a user installs a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

Is there a way to configure a gem's gemspec to print an important informational message right after someone downloads and installs the gem using `gem install`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, use `post_install_message` in the gemspec ([docs](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Specification.html)).

You can see how [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/) does it [in its gemspec](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/e38baab559bb078ee421676b752d9877e5828b48/httparty.gemspec#L18).