# User input while installing a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I would like to intercept my gem installation process and receive some user input. How do I do that? I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and bundler for my gem development and hosting it on rubygems.org.

Alternatively, is there a way to pass arguments?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea; many people (esp. sysadmins) prefer non-interactive installations.

Comment: I agree with maerics. A possible alternative is to show a post installation message with further instructions for the user. How you show such a message is described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543001/is-there-a-way-to-print-a-message-after-a-user-installs-a-ruby-gem

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply- I've updated the question.

Comment: Maybe check for environment variables instead?  Always best to pick sane defaults so that a "hands-off" install still works.

Comment: unfortunately most ruby gem installations have their stdout redirected to a file, so you may not be able to prompt anyway...

Comment: @maerics yes, I thought of having a default value for most installs- not just hands off ones. Unfortunately env variables won't be sufficient. Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: use post installation configuration program. Display a message in the end of the installation and ask the user to run a program that does configuration. Thats many gems do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the only way of achieving this is by adding a post installation message and then having in your bin a cmd along the line of config-mygem to achieve the same thing. Not exactly what I was looking for, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Normally to pass "arguments" you would require the use of environment variables. Things like ruby-oci8 need these to compile for Oracle database use.